# Plone navigation with one-language-per-folder site

Tags: python, localization, multilingual, plone, linguaplone

I am developing a multi-lingual site with Plone. I want to have one language per folder but the Plone navigation UI is causing problems.

I have several different folders in my root, such as en, de, nl, etcetera. Inside those folders is the actual content, such as en/news, nl/nieuw, de/nachrichten, etcetera. I have set up Plone Language Tool to pick the language setting from the URL, but the navigation is not showing the correct items.

The tabbed navigation is making tabs for the language folders. The path bar is showing `"You are here: Home -> en -> news"`. How can I change the tabbed navigation and the path bar to show the items inside the language specific folder? I want to have a tab for "news", not for "en" on the English site. The path bar should show `"You are here: Home -> news"`.

I am using Plone 3.2.3 with Plone Language Tool 3.0.2 and LinguaPlone 2.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each language folder should implement INavigationRoot.
You can set that up by going to the ZMI, finding the folder, and going to the Interfaces tab. There you will find plone.app.layout.navigation.interfaces.INavigationRoot. Click it, and navigation will treat it as the root of the tree.
(Note that in Plone 3.3 the support for INavigationRoot has gotten better, so you may want to upgrade. -- edit by Maurits)